# JQuery dataTable pagination optimization

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

I have an app that need a quick fix.

The server sends back all table elements (about 2 thousands ...) and dataTable just renders everything at one shot. The consequence is that the browser takes extra long time to render the whole page, but just display the first page (about 10 rows).

Without changing the server side code, what can I do to optimize the dataTable to not to render the whole page?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"deferRender": true`

Example":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt",
        "deferRender": true
    } );
} );
```

http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html